# count all possible 2-grams in each row

Tags: python, csv, pandas, n-gram

Let's say I have a csv file like this (in reality I have more than a 100+ different services possible) :

```
user_id, services
user_1, "s1,s2,s1,s4,s2,s3,s2"
user_2, "s2,s3,s2,s1,s4"
```

and I would like to have eventually this, mostly using python and pandas if possible :

```
user_id, c12,c21,c13,c31,c14,c42,c23,c32,c14,c43,c34
user_1, 1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0
user_2, 0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1
```

where `cij` = number of `sequence si,sj for each user`

Ideally, I would like it to be usable not only for a sequence of 2 but also a sequence of 3

What I found on SO is an overall count of si sj, but not a count like this one. I guess I need a pivot table at some point, and also n-gram but I don't know how to mix it together :/

Thanks for your help

Comment: Its would be nice if you're data is an easy copy+paste for people who will try to solve your problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recreating your data (but having split the service column in different columns)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['user_id'] = [1,2]
df['s1'] = [0, 1]
df['s2'] = [1, 1]
df['s3'] = [1,0]
```

Then we can combine:

```
cols = list(df)[1:]
for c1, c2 in itertools.permutations(c,2):
    df[c1+c2] = df[c1] & df[c2]
```

By changing 2 in 3 you can add 3-grams instead of n-grams.

EDIT:

I now understand your problem better. Below is a solution that works with strings. First we create some data:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['user1',"s1,s2,s1,s4,s2,s3,s2"],['user2',"s2,s3,s2,s1,s4"]])
df.columns = ['userid','services']
```

For n-grams we use a flexible function (as you indicated you might want to use higher level n-grams)

```
def find_ngrams(input_list, n):
   return zip(*[input_list[i:] for i in range(n)])
```

We count the occurrences and create a dataframe:

```
results = {}
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    list_of_services = row['services'].split(',')
    combinations = ['c_{}_{}'.format(c1,c2) for c1, c2 in find_ngrams(list_of_services, 2)]
    results[row['userid']] = {k: 1 for k in combinations}

df2.from_dict(results).transpose()
```

For your toy example it returns:

```
        c_s1_s2  c_s1_s4  c_s2_s1  c_s2_s3  c_s3_s2  c_s4_s2
user1      1.0      1.0      1.0      1.0      1.0      1.0
user2      NaN      1.0      1.0      1.0      1.0      NaN
```

Comment: Not sure this answers the OPs question, given this just says whether any user has `s1` & `s2` (i.e. just treating everything like sets) not if is `s1` is followed by `s2` in the list `s1,s2,s1,s4,s2`.

Comment: The thing is that not all my users have the same number of services, so when I convert my csv file with each service as a column into a dataframe I have an error. I edit my original post in order it to be clearer

Answer (score 1):

Just using python and `itertools` then you can do this using the `itertools.pairwise` recipe.

```
import itertools as it

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = it.tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)
```

Assuming you are reading the file using `csv.DictReader()` then:

```
>>> from collection import Counter
>>> services = ['s1', 's2', 's3', 's4']        # Total set of services
>>> combs = list(it.permutations(services, 2)) # All combinations of services
>>> counts = {row['user_id']: Counter(pairwise(row['services'].split(','))) for row in reader}
>>> [{user: {p: c[p] for p in combs} for user, c in counts.items()}]
[{'user_1': {('s1', 's2'): 1,
   ('s1', 's3'): 0,
   ('s1', 's4'): 1,
   ('s2', 's1'): 1,
   ('s2', 's3'): 1,
   ('s2', 's4'): 0,
   ('s3', 's1'): 0,
   ('s3', 's2'): 1,
   ('s3', 's4'): 0,
   ('s4', 's1'): 0,
   ('s4', 's2'): 1,
   ('s4', 's3'): 0},
  'user_2': {('s1', 's2'): 0,
   ('s1', 's3'): 0,
   ('s1', 's4'): 1,
   ('s2', 's1'): 1,
   ('s2', 's3'): 1,
   ('s2', 's4'): 0,
   ('s3', 's1'): 0,
   ('s3', 's2'): 1,
   ('s3', 's4'): 0,
   ('s4', 's1'): 0,
   ('s4', 's2'): 0,
   ('s4', 's3'): 0}}]
```

Comment: Thank you, but I think it would be more complicated than that : indeed, I only wrote a small sample of my data (to simplify, but maybe I shouldn't have), but in reality I have more than 100+ services different, so doing by hand all the different combinations in the def of pairwise is almost impossible :/ 
Besides, isn't it possible to have the result as a dataframe rather than a dictionary ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... `pairwise()` goes through whatever list you provide 10, 1000, 10000000 items. And constructs a counter of all occurrences `(si, sj)`. There is no additional hand coding based on the dataset. If you need `n-grams` then it's pretty trivial to turn `pairwise()` in to `nwise()`.